# Let function $f : X → Y$ , with $|X| = m$ and $|Y|= n$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I found this question in text book. I am looking at the solution but I can't understand it. Can anyone enlighten me. Thanks!

Let function $f : X → Y$ , with $|X| = m$ and $|Y|= n$.

1. How many functions $f$ are possible ?

Solution:$n^m$

2. How many one-to-one functions $f$ are possible, given $m≤n$?

Solution:$P(n, m) = n!/(m−n)!$

3. How many one-to-one correspondence $f$ are possible, given $m = n$ ?

Solution: $P(n, n) = n!/(n−n)! = n!$

Comment: You have to tell us how you have attempted to understand it, and where your understanding is failing you. The first one seems obvious to me, I have to  see the gap in your thinking, for example.

Comment: Here's a couple of questions to get you started on question 1: How many choices does such a function $f$ have for each element of $X$? Can you combine this with the number of elements of $X$?

Answer (score 3):

1) For each of the $m$ elements $x\in X$ there are $n$ choices for $f(x)\in Y$. That gives $$n\times n\times\cdots\times n=n^m$$ possibilities.

2) Let $X=\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$. There are $n$ choices for $f(x_1)$. After that there are $n-1$ choices for $f(x_2)$, et cetera. So we find $$n\times(n-1)\times\cdots\times(n-m+1)=\frac{n!}{(m-n)!}$$ possibilities. Btw, note that the LHS also works if $m>n$.

3) Just a matter of substituting $m=n$ in the previous formula.

Answer (score 0):

Question $\#1$.

Someone might think that way. Let's say we have a function
$$f: \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_m\} \to \{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n\}.$$  We can correspond the variable $x_1$ to $n$ distinct $y$ values (namely $x_1\mapsto y_1$ or $x_1 \mapsto y_2$ or ... or  $x_1 \mapsto y_n$), $x_2$ to $n$ distinct $y$ values... and finally, we can correspond $x_m$ to $n$ distinct $y$ values. So, summing up all the combinations yields the total numbers of functions we can have, which is $\underbrace{n\cdot n\cdots n}_{m- \text{ times}} = n^m.$

---

Question $\#2$.

In this case, we want to answer this equivalent question. Assume we have the ordered $m-$ tuple $(x_1, \ldots, x_m)$. How many distinct $m-$ tuples can we make from the set $\{y_1, \ldots ,y_n\}$ without repetition (we demand no repetition, since we want our functions to be $1-1$)? Also, notice here that order matters.

---

Question $\#3$ follows directly from the previous question.